restricting a function changes its singular points and analyticity?
Let define $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{2\}$. Then it is clear that, $f(z)$ has singular point at $z=2$ (Namely pole of order 1 at $z=2$).
However, if I update the definition of domain of a function (say I restrict it) :
Define, $f(z) =\frac{1}{z-2}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus∆(0,3)$ where $∆(0, 3)$ is the open disk with center $0$ and radius $3$. Then Is $z=2$ is still a singular point of $f(z)? $
If not, then, Is f(z) with this new domain of definition, becomes analytic at point $z=2$?
Please help me...

That depends on definitions. A non-silly definition does not call a function analytic at a point that is not in its domain. Also, any analytic continuation of f beyond whatever restricted domain you have there would still fail to be analytic at $2$.

@TorstenSchoeneberg sir, what's about singular point? Is $f(z)$ with new restricted domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus∆(0,3)$ still have singular point at $z=2$?

A point which is not in a function's domain should not be called analytic, or singular, or anything else except "not in the domain of $f$", as far as I am concerned. But as said, that might be a matter of definitions or conventions.
